# row skew and memory skew values in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I ended up digging into Data Skew after noticing that our cluster runs hot on 2-3 leaves after a lot of insert operations (we have 30 leaves with 32G ram each). Basically our memory reaches almost 100% on those nodes causing a cluster blockage.Restarting those leaves did not free up the memory (in table memory reaches the maximum allocated size). What helped at that stage was allocating more memory to those 2-3 leaves (they are aws instances). However this is not a desired approach- it was a desperate workaround. Strange is that except these 2-3 leaves that are running out of memory, the other leaves are at around 20-30% memory consumption.

Checking this https://docs.memsql.com/docs/data-skew and running those queries i have noticed that all values for row_skew   are < 10 %  but memory_skew  values are for some tables > 40% .

So i was wondering if there is anything that needs to be checked , improved , optimized?

Answer (score 0):

Low row skew but high memory skew could be because you have variable-size data types (such as strings like varchar), and for some reason there is skew in that some partitions have many more bigger strings.

First, you can look for which specific fields are highly skewed - maybe something like select partition_id(), avg(length(s)) from t group by partition_id(). Then depending on what you find you may want to see if there is unexpected problems with the data, or if you need to change the shard key.

Answer (score 0):

Check for orphan partition on the nodes with higher memory use (SHOW CLUSTER STATUS or EXPLAIN CLEAR ORPHAN PARTITIONS).